# 404 Docker reverse proxy accessing reverse-proxy location

Tags: nginx, docker, jenkins

I am working with docker containers with reverse proxy for jenkins container and got into this issue.
My nginx custom config is as follow:

```
upstream jenkins {
    server 172.17.0.2:8080;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name jenkins;
    location /jenkins {
    proxy_pass http://172.17.0.2:8080;
}
```

Also, /etc/nginx/nginx.conf doesn't have any default root directory but still when I tried to access http://localhost/jenkins, it is giving me **404 with Problem accessing /jenkins. Reason:Not Found**

I checked nginx error logs and it has **"/etc/nginx/html/index.html" is not found**

Though I have not set any /etc/nginx/html/ config, why it is giving me 404 error?
Can someone clarify my doubt?

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4uwJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems more approriate for the nginx part. If you declare an upstream, use it :

```
upstream jenkins {
    server 172.17.0.2:8080;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name jenkins;
    location /jenkins {
        proxy_pass http://jenkins;
    }
}
```

For the docker part, I recommand using port mapping if you can. Because IP of docker containers change, you will have to edit you config file each time you recreate the jenkins container. With something like `docker container run -d -p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080 my-jenkins-container-image` you can modify your nginx config to something like :

```
upstream jenkins {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name jenkins;
    location /jenkins {
        proxy_pass http://jenkins;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use the container name inside the upstream block, since nginx and jenkins are in the same docker net, but I still got the default index page.. https://gist.github.com/tuxerrante/b417d54eabc7a870c3bbb97dc9494420